# navigator.msSaveBlob function is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, csv

I have used `msSaveBlob()` command to download a CSV file. I am facing an issue although `navigate.msSaveBlob()` is returning `true`, and there are no errors on console. I am being prompted that

> File Couldn't be downloaded. Retry or Cancel.

I am working on IE11, and OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.
I also tried updating IE, but it is still not working.

I also tried the [samples from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx), but facing the same issue.
Kindly suggest me how to resolve this issue.

**Code Snippet:**

```
var blob = new Blob(["Sample String\r\n,For Checking, msSaveBlob"],{
    type:'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
});

if(navigator.msSaveBlob){
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,"sample.csv");
}
```

Comment: please use code formatting if there's code in your question

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue and we found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/cant-download-files-with-ie-11/3846db64-b36b-4e76-a7b4-b9bf86e1be24?page=1).

Basically is a problem with user permissions to the temp folder on the IE. Because in some computers happen and others don't.
So, I changed the folder on "Internet options" > General > settings > temporary internet files > move folder, and here I've chosen a folder with all the permissions active.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same issue as yours in 2021 :>
And I referred to the link in zetadaro's answer, and it helps!

But the solution I used it's not to choose a folder with all permissions as he mentioned.

Please refer to this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbShs.png)
That's to say, the issue I met caused by the IE download setting!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30262807)